# How to hide datalist on scroll in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

In Chrome, if input[list] with datalist is placed in a scrollable container, the datalist will remain at the same place after scroll, check out [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/lucifer63/py91jxm8/):

1. Click the input, the datalist will appear,
2. `Scroll the container`,
3. Get curious why the datalist didn't hide despite the input is not visible anymore.

That's it. Firefox and other browsers handle this situation without any troubles - datalist gets hidden on scroll.

So, the question is: is there any way to hide datalist on scroll even if it is in nested containers in Chrome?

Update: this bug is already [filed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=674447), [twice](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=849616). Waiting for Chrome team for a resolution!

Comment: Could be a bug or the way chrome wanted it to be implemented. You could set blur to the input on scroll to get rid of it

Comment: @Huangism, that's actually what i asked about - is it a bug or just some developer' decision. In first case i can at least try to write a bugreport.

Comment: I think you should submit a bug report for it and see how they respond

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector('.main').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
  if (isChrome) {
    document.querySelector('input').blur();
  }
}, false);
```

[JSFiddle version](https://jsfiddle.net/BlueWolf153622/vp8dz5m4/)